# Known proof of conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In my elementary number theory book (Rosen, 8th edition), there's a problem formulated as followed:

> 24. Show that $1^{(p-1)} + 2^{(p-1)} + 3^{(p-1)} + \cdots + (p-1)^{(p-1)} \equiv -1 \pmod p$ whenever $p$ is prime. (It has been conjectured that the converse of this is also true.)

Does there exist a proof of the converse, and if not, why is it so much harder to prove than the original statement?

Comment: The original statement follows immediately from Fermat's little theorem

Comment: I changed \text{ }(\text{mod } p) to \pmod p. That is standard usage. (If more than one object (such as the letter p in this case) is to be inside the parentheses, then one must use {curly braces}; thus \equiv-1\pmod{43} yields $\equiv-1\pmod{43}.$ If you omit the braces and write \equiv-1\pmod43 then you see $\equiv-1\pmod43.$) $\qquad$

Comment: Yeah, I was able to prove that...but what about the converse? I don't think you can apply Fermat's Little Theorem in the same way. Also, thanks @MichaelHardy, I didn't know how to use the mod function in MathJax.

Comment: @Connington Exactly, this answers your question why it is much harder to prove the converse (if it is true). I do not know whether a proof is known (the text indicates it is not), but there is no obvious way to even approach it.

Comment: It's the [Agoh-Giuga conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoh%E2%80%93Giuga_conjecture).